# Run-time dependency on generated file in CMake

Tags: cmake, parallel-builds

I have a test (`add_executable(MyTest ...)`) which needs a file at run-time. The file is generated using a custom command. I would like to model that *run-time* dependency in CMake.

Currently, there is a *build-time* dependency on the generated file using `add_dependencies(MyTest GenerateFile)` where `GenerateFile` is a custom target that depends on the custom command's output. **Disadvantage:** `MyTest` does not start compiling code until `GenerateFile` has finished building. This is unnecessary -- I would like to build `MyTest` and generate the file in parallel.

Another option I considered was to add a new target `MyTestAndGenerateFile` that depends on both `MyTest` and `GenerateFile`. **Disadvantage:** Calling `make MyTest` does not generate the file any more. One has to remember to call `make MyTestAndGenerateFile` instead.

Alternatively, the new target could be called `MyTest` and the test could be added using `add_executable(MyTest_Code ...)`. **Disadvantage:** When using the Visual Studio generator, the test code will now be located in a project called `MyTest_Code` instead of `MyTest`, which breaks naming conventions. Also, you now have to *build* the `MyTest` project, but *run* the `MyTest_Code` project, so you cannot use *Set as start-up project* any more.

In short, I am looking for a form of `add_dependencies` saying that the dependency is not needed at build time, but rather at run time.

Comment: CMake can't track how are you launching compiled binaries. The only way to make it track it is to add a custom target that would run it.

Comment: @arrowd Maybe "run-time dependency" is misleading here, but I could not think of a better term. I only want to make sure that `GenerateFile` is brought up to date whenever `MyTest` is built, but without `MyTest` waiting for `GenerateFile` to finish before starting to build.

Comment: You may find [craig scott's article on test fixtures in cmake](https://crascit.com/2016/10/18/test-fixtures-with-cmake-ctest/) helpful. you could create a test which actually just replaces the custom command and sets up the generated file. and then make your other test depend on that fixture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to add a test that invokes the target `GenerateFile`, and make your actual test depend on the former. Something like this:

```
add_test(NAME MakeGenerateFile COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target GenerateFile)
add_test(MyTest MyTest)
set_tests_properties(MyTest PROPERTIES DEPENDS MakeGenerateFile)
```